# Multiple commands produce Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, login, facebook, error404

Estoy desarrollando una app en XCode y luego de incluir el framework de FB Login me tira este error

```
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/Tomas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Finanzas-hjqzbozundaryueuvtrolftccfuo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Finanzas.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework':

1) Target 'Finanzas' has copy command from '/Users/Tomas/Desktop/Finanzas/Carthage/Build/iOS/FBSDKCoreKit.framework' to '/Users/Tomas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Finanzas-hjqzbozundaryueuvtrolftccfuo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Finanzas.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework'

2) That command depends on command in Target 'Finanzas': script phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”
```

Ya probé con el modo legacy, reinstale los frameworks, hice build del framework individualmente y nada.

Gracias de ante mano.

Answer (score 0):

A mi me paso algo muy similar en una ocasión estaba trabajando con google maps, lo descargué desde el sitio oficial de google y lo instalé manualmente, al tiempo, se volvieron muy populares los Pods y decidí integrarlo, pero no borre el que habia integrado manualmente, lo que paso fue que me marco ese error de multiple commands, parece que tienes lo mismo, borra uno y tu problema estará resuelto, borra tu contenido del folder de DerivedData y listo...

Saludos.